# How to create a dynamic background image for components in Vue using props?

Tags: css, vue.js, data-binding, vue-composition-api, vue-props

**Objective**

I want to pass the *path* of an image as a prop to a component. I want the component to use the prop to dynamically generate the background image.

All my images in an assets folder in the Vue src folder.
The path looks like *'@/assets/images/subject/computers.jpeg'*

**Problem**

No background image appears

This is what renders on the page:

[image]

However, nothing shows up

**Strange Behaviour**

For some reason, adding the exact same path name *'@/assets/images/subject/computers.jpeg'* in CSS works (Adding it in the <style> tags). It just doesn't work if it's v-bind inline style.

Here is what it looks like in my CSS

[image]

The problem with this though, is that it is not dynamically rendered CSS.

I inspected the element further and noticed some strange behavior. As you can see, the inline style is reading the image path as *'@/assets/images/subject/computers.jpeg'* (element.style in image below).

Whereas adding the path in CSS, changes *'@/assets/images/subject/computers.jpeg'* to *'http://localhost:8080/img/computers.7f3748eb.jpeg'*, which then correctly renders the background image.

[image]

**Question**

I suppose my question is twofold:

1. How would you dynamically render a background image in Vue with props? Or is there a better way to do this?
2. Why does binding inline styles not resolve the path (keeps using '@'), while adding it directly in the <script> tags does resolve the path?

**Solution**

Okay, big thank you to ***tao*** & ***Bernard Borg*** for helping me wrap my head around this.

I was able to solve this using computed properties like so:

```
const imgSrc = computed(() => require(`@/assets/images/subject/${props.subject.image}`))
```

Because of the way VueLoader (which is default in Vue) resolves the paths, I couldn't store the '@' path in the prop itself. Instead, the prop is just the image/file name *(ex. "computers.jpeg")*, and the computed property with require() handles resolving the prepended path to the image.

Afterwards, I added the computed property to my binded inline style like so:

```
<div class="subject-wrapper" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: `url('${imgSrc}')` }">
```

Voila! It finally works.

**TLDR**

Pass ***only*** the image/file name as a prop, and prepend the path using require() in a computed property.

Cheers

Comment: Under the hood, Vue uses [VueLoader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/) which resolves the correct paths to assets depending on environment (it has a different path when served (dev) then when built (prod)). Read [Asset URL Handling](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#asset-url-handling). Specifically, the **transform rules**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Webpack (Vue-cli), the `@` symbol is an alias for the src folder.

> If the URL starts with @, it's also interpreted as a module request. This is useful if your webpack config has an alias for @, which by default points to /src in any project created by vue-cli

[Source](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules)

If you're using Vite, you probably have the following in vite.config.js;

```js
resolve: {
     alias: {
          "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
          ...
     }
}
```

VueLoader transforms asset urls when they're located in thee following html tags: `video`, `source`, `img`, `image` (svgs) and `use` (svgs). Moreover, it also transforms asset urls when they're in the  tag if you have VueLoader configured to use `css-loader`.

> All compiled CSS are processed by css-loader, which parses url() and resolves them as module requests.

[Source](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html)

This asset url transformation does not happen when you're v-binding a style property.

You can use this mechanism to pass transformed paths to a different component (for example, a component from a library). Despite this, you would still need to declare every single path as mentioned by @tao.

> The relevant point here is that VueLoader has to read all the possible paths when compiling the app and resolve them.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import BackgroundImageViewer from './components/BackgroundImageViewer.vue'
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const hiddenImage = ref<HTMLImageElement>();
const thePath = ref();

onMounted(() => {
    if (hiddenImage.value) {
        thePath.value = hiddenImage.value.src;
        hiddenImage.value.src = "";
    }
});
</script>

<template>
    <img src="@/assets/vue.svg" ref="hiddenImage" hidden />
    <BackgroundImageViewer :path="thePath"/>
</template>
```

As @tao also mentioned, if the number of different images is too much you can opt to place the images in your project's `public` folder.

Edit: You can also use the `require` method with an `if-else` tree, `ternary` or `switch` statement to get the relative path to your image (if the number of images that can be set as the background isn't too much - otherwise use the `public` folder).

With `Vite` you can use the [`vite-plugin-require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-require) plugin to make `require()` work.

Comment: The proper way to keep dynamic asset urls working across environments, as well as in apps served inside a folder of a server is to use `require()`, which works with relative paths. Example: `const bgSrc = computed(() => condition ? require('pathA') : require('pathB'))`. Using `location.origin` breaks quite a few use cases.

Comment: Ok - what condition are you referring to?

Comment: Any condition. Please read the title of the question you're answering.

Comment: What if there are infinite options?

Comment: That's irrelevant. Use `switch`. The relevant point here is that VueLoader has to read ***all the possible paths*** when compiling the app and resolve them. I'm guessing one wants their app to work when deployed. Having it working only while serving is borderline pointless.

Comment: If there are infinite options you don't place the asset in `assets`. You place them in `public` and the responsibility of the asset being found in the public folder is deferred to the developer, who has to put all the assets which will ever be requested in that folder. VueLoader is no longer handling those.

Comment: @tao please correct my updated answer if any information is incorrect - I couldn't figure out how to make `require` work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251480/discussion-between-tao-and-bernard-borg).